# Pass Current Table Row values to a subcomponent with onClick of a button in React (Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image: Parent To Child in React]

Edit, Get App, Account Tree and Group Icons have onclick that redirects to subcomponents. Particular Row Data should be passed for the subcomponents

```
{recordsAfterPaging().map((row, index) =>{
                              return(
                                              <TableBody>
                                                      <TableRow key={index}>
                                                                <TableCell>{row.groupName}</TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell className={classes.groupOwner}>{row.groupOwner}</TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>{row.attestationRvwDate}</TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>{row.expiryDate}</TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>
                                                                <IconButton onClick={editRolePopup} className={classes.editIcon}>
                                                                        <Edit />
                                                                </IconButton>
                                                                </TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>
                                                                        <IconButton onClick={getGroupReport} className={classes.icon}>
                                                                                <GetApp />
                                                                        </IconButton>
                                                                </TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>
                                                                        <IconButton onClick={(row) => manageSiteComp({row}) } className={classes.icon}>
                                                                                <AccountTree />
                                                                        </IconButton>
                                                                </TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>
                                                                        <IconButton onClick={() => manageUsersComp({row}) } size="medium" className={classes.icon}>
                                                                                <Group />
                                                                        </IconButton>
                                                                </TableCell>
                                                      </TableRow>
                                              </TableBody>
                      )})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to post the update. Found out the answer from [Material UI Documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#table) (Sorting and Selecting Table). Use a Checkbox/Radio button in the first column and get the logic in the onclick event of checkbox.

```
const getRowData = (event, row) => {
          const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(row[0]);
          console.log(`Get Row Data`, row);
          let newSelected = [];
          if (selectedIndex === -1) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, row[0]);
          } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
          } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
          } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(
              selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
              selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
            );
          }
          setSelected(newSelected);
        };



{recordsAfterPaging().map((row , index) =>{
                                const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.siteUrl);
                                const labelId = `offboard-row-${index}`;
                                      return(
                                                        <TableRow  onClick={(e) => getRowData(e, row)}  tabIndex={-1} role="checkbox" hover aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                                                        key={row.siteUrl} selected={isItemSelected}>
                                                                <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                                                    <Radio size='small' checked={isItemSelected} inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }} />
                                                                </TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell > {row.requestID} </TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell> {row.siteName} </TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>{row.siteUrl}</TableCell>
                                                                <TableCell>{row.onboardDate}</TableCell>
                                                        </TableRow>
                              )})}
```